# How to add set comprehension like union and intersect to Python class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, set

I want to create a class without inheriting `frozenset` (unless I can inherit both `tuple` and `frozenset` without getting `TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict`) where I can use set comprehension like `|`, `&`, `<`, and `>` operators.

```
A = {"first"}
B = {"second"}
C = A | B

class Custom(tuple):
    def __new__(self, pair, **metadata):
        return super(Custom, self).__new__(self,tuple(pair))
    def __init__(self, pair, **metadata):
        self.pair = tuple(pair)
        self.metadata = metadata

pair_1 = Custom(["A","B"])
pair_2 = Custom(["B","C"])
pair_1 | pair_2
```

I couldn't find any "special" functions that do this.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with this class? An ordered set?

Comment: Essentially yea.  I want to be able to index it but also do set comprehension.

Comment: Set comprehension? Do you just mean the overloaded bitwise operators for set operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special methods are all documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names); you need `__and__`, `__or__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__`.